# How do I bind a Dataset to a Datagrid with an ObjectDataProvider?

Tags: binding, master-detail, objectdataprovider

i've got another binding problem.
This time I wanted to rebuild the Master-Detail grid shown here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples#masterdetail

But I got this Error: The name "AirplaneDataProvider" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WpfApplicationDataSetTest"

Here's my code

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationDataSetTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationDataSetTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="AirplaneDataProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type local:AirplaneDataProvider}"/>        
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Airplanes" ObjectInstance="{StaticResource AirplaneDataProvider}" MethodName="GetAirplanes" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <DataGrid Name="DGMaster" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Airplanes}}" SelectedValuePath="AirplaneID">
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

c#:

namespace WpfApplicationDataSetTest
{ 
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    public class AirplaneDataProvider
    {
        private AirplaneTestDataSetTableAdapters.AirplaneTableAdapter AirTA;
        private AirplaneTestDataSet AirTDS;

        public AirplaneDataProvider()
        {
            AirTDS = new AirplaneTestDataSet();
            AirTA = new AirplaneTestDataSetTableAdapters.AirplaneTableAdapter();
            AirTA.Fill(AirTDS.Airplane);
        }

        public DataView GetAirplanes()
        {
            return AirTDS.Airplane.DefaultView;
        }
    }
}
```

}

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Put the AirplaneDataProvider class into separated file.

Now you have it inside MainWindow class. hope that is the problem.